# Spark compiles with Eclipse on Windows but not javac on CentOS VM

Tags: java, linux, apache-spark, javac

I am trying to compile the spark example from

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

```
/* SimpleApp.java */

import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;

public class Sparktest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String logFile = args[0] + "/README.md"; // Should be some file on your system
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<String> logData = sc.textFile(logFile).cache();

    long numAs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
      public Boolean call(String s) { return s.contains("a"); }
    }).count();

    long numBs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
      public Boolean call(String s) { return s.contains("b"); }
    }).count();

    System.out.println("Lines with a: " + numAs + ", lines with b: " + numBs);
  }
}
```

if I copy the code into eclipse and add the

```
spark-assembly-1.3.1.2.3.0.0-2130-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2130.jar
```

file to the build path through eclipse everything resolves and eclipse places my class files in the projects bin directory.

When I move the code over to my CentOS VM and execute the following line

```
javac -cp ./spark-assembly-1.3.1.2.3.0.0-2130-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2130.jar:. ./Sparktest.java
```

in a directory with the jar file it complains about

```
 package org.apache.spark.api does not exist
 package org.apache.spark     does not exist
 package org.apache.spark.api.java.function does not exist
```

I have opened the jar file with 7zip on Windows, and know that that directory structure exists and all the class are in the jar. I'm still new to command line compiling java, but am pretty sure that there is some kind of directory structure thing going on here.

What combination of a javac command and directory structure do I need to get this to compile?

Comment: did you try to omit the ./
like;
javac -cp spark-assembly-1.3.1.2.3.0.0-2130-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2130.jar:. Sparktest.java

Comment: I might sound stupid but did you try using -classpath instead of -cp

Comment: Can you run eclipse on Centos and see if it compiles in eclipse as well?

Comment: another option would be to update the PATh variable to include the location of spark-assembly jar using export PATH=$PATH:<your-path>

Comment: @Peter Lawrey CentOS is command line only. That's why I was doing the development in Windows.

Comment: I should have said my copy of CentOS is command line only right now. I am running it on a VM. I didn't mean to imply that CentOS had no GUI.

Comment: @SemicolonsandDuctTape You can install the GUI and eclipse for CentOS so you can compile, test, debug things locally.